# Yeti problem - can't find module 'jade'

Tags: javascript, yahoo, node.js, yeti

I've just installed [Yeti](http://github.com/yui/yeti) from Yahoo, but when I go to `http://localhost:8000/` I get this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jade'
at loadModule (node.js:289:15)
at require (node.js:420:14)
at ServerResponse.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yeti/0.1.0/dependencies/express/view.js:258:46)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yeti/0.1.0/package/lib/server.js:28:13)
at pass (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yeti/0.1.0/dependencies/connect/middleware/router.js:67:31)
at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yeti/0.1.0/dependencies/connect/middleware/router.js:80:14
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:50:25)
at node.js:773:9
```

I also want to mention that i have installed this using the installer package from Yahoo! http://yuilibrary.com/downloads/download.php?file=3716057163a82b4b00c2a00ab0bb186e

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem using the "Express" framework and I solved it by typing `npm install -d` in directory where my app was created.

Comment: What does this flag actually do?

Comment: @ShaneChin: Errr... It's nothing more than a verbose output flag? See `npm help config` or [these docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html) for reference. The net effect is nothing more than installing all of `package.json`'s specified modules into `node_modules` in your local directory.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't installed yeti, but by looking at the node stack trace, it looks like the maintainer left out the jade module.

From the console try:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm install jade
```

or

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/npm install jade
```

depending on your permissions.

Repeat for any other missing modules. If you're still stuck, I can download it and check it out.

Comment: Maybe the installer didn't install the npm binary. Maybe see if you can find it. Does 'type npm' return anything? Is there any file called npm in the /usr/local directory? 'find /usr/local -name npm'

Comment: Maybe binary is installed to `/usr/bin/npm`, if npm is installed via `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`. Somehow I have the very same error with `jade` and I've done `sudo /usr/bin/npm install jade`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/node ~/.node_modules
```

---

So the full `npm` install process for me was:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
ln -s /usr/lib/node ~/.node_modules
sudo npm install jade
node ./build.js
```

*(do not use `sudo` if not required)*